# Nullcheck before int.TryParse

Tags: c#, int

I have code where many strings get parsed into integer values.

```
string item = null; //or a value
int result;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && int.TryParse(item, out result))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Is it really required to check `IsNullOrEmpty` each time? If it is `null` or empty, a parse should fail.

Comment: You could test it yourself before asking. No, it's not required. `TryParse` returns `false` then.

Comment: result would be 0, if try parsing failed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Could do, but this mechanical turk approach allows for a fire-and-forget style solution to the problem. Spend similar time creating a quick question, go for lunch, come back to the answer - there are a few words describing this phenomenon, but they are primarily opinion-based ;-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth stop trolling, that doesn't add any value here

Comment: @TimSchmelter there must be a reason for this `IsNullOrEmpty` check. Does it improve performance because `TryParse` isn't a simple method and by checking for `null` before, the application performance can be imporved? As mentioned there are _many_ such checks in the code

Comment: @Toshi Neither does your question mate.

Comment: Of course I tried it before and noticed the result - i'm more searching for a reason to check for null before parsing

Comment: @Toshi: why there must be a reason? I suspect the reason is that the author of that code didn't know that `int.TryParse` handles it. Actually it handles the null-case first so there is no perfomance difference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is redundant here because [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) handles that case by returning `false`. So this is more concise:

```
int result;
if (int.TryParse(item, out result))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

MSDN:

> The **conversion fails if the s parameter is null or String.Empty**, is
>   not of the correct format, or represents a number less than MinValue
>   or greater than MaxValue.

Answer (score 2):

`Int.TryParse` will return a boolean (`true` if it succeeds), so you can write:

```
string item = null; //or a value
int result;
if (int.TryParse(item, out result))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to check for null or empty, if you are using `.TryParse` for the conversion. Since the the return value will be false if the conversion failed. So it is safe to use like this:

```
string item = null; //or a value
int result;
if(int.TryParse(item, out result))
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
  // you can show conversion failure message here
  // or can proceed with value 0
}
```

Additional note : If you are processing the conversion using`int.Parse` then it would be great to check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` since `null` cause `ArgumentNullException` and Empty string cause `FormatException`